# Query with join or without join?

Tags: sql, join

I'm new to sql, What's the difference between

```
select vehicle.plates, make, model 
from vehicle 
   join registration on registration.plates = vehicle.plates 
where country = 'Japan';
```

And

```
select vehicle.plates, make, model
from registration, vehicle
where registration.plates = vehicle.plates and country=’Japan’;
```

Comment: Both queries have a "join". The second one uses an old-style implicit join that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query is ANSI compliant, the other one is not.

The queries ought to return the same results, though.

Comment: The second is also ANSI compliant - in fact that was the ANSI standard before 1992

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Didn't even know that. I was under the impression it was a deprecated syntax. I know it still works, but the JOIN syntax is the preferred one nowadays. Learnt something new :)